# How to read inline image in email body using Mailkit

Tags: c#, mailkit

I have sent myself a test email which has an image in the body of the email.  This image is not an attachment, just pasted into the body of the email.

I am using MailKit to read this incoming email, but cannot find how to access that image.

I'm using:

```
MimeMessage message = client.Inbox.GetMessage(uid);
```

If I use `message.ToString()`, I can see that it is there:

```
...
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="image001.png"; size=4570;
        creation-date="Mon, 16 Sep 2019 09:21:07 GMT";
        modification-date="Mon, 16 Sep 2019 09:21:07 GMT"
Content-ID: <image001.png@01D56A4B.7CD234E0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJUAAAAlCAY...
```

And I assume the base64 encoded lines are the actual image, but how do I get at it?

*EDIT*

Here is my test code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ImapClient client = new ImapClient();
        client.Connect("...
        client.Authenticate("...
        client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
        IList<UniqueId> uids = client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.All);
        foreach (UniqueId uid in uids)
        {
            MimeMessage message = client.Inbox.GetMessage(uid);

            IList<IMessageSummary> info = client.Inbox.Fetch(new[] { uid }, MessageSummaryItems.All);

            foreach (MimeEntity me in message.Attachments)
                HandleMimeEntity(me, 1);
        }
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }

    static void HandleMimeEntity(MimeEntity entity)
    {
        int i, j;

        Multipart multipart = entity as Multipart;

        if (multipart != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("multipart");
            for (i = 0; i < multipart.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + " - " + multipart[i].ContentType.MimeType + " (" + multipart[i].IsAttachment + ")");
                HandleMimeEntity(multipart[i]);
            }
            return;
        }

        MessagePart rfc822 = entity as MessagePart;

        if (rfc822 != null)
        {
            MimeMessage message = rfc822.Message;
            Console.WriteLine("mimemessage - " + message.Subject);

            HandleMimeEntity(message.Body, lvl + 1);
            return;
        }

        MimePart part = (MimePart)entity;
        Console.WriteLine("mimepart - " + part.FileName);

        // do something with the MimePart, such as save content to disk
    }
```

Comment: What do you get in `message.Body`?

Comment: I would say to search in the html for the tag "img" and read his value, then convert to base64 or if it is link download the image

Comment: I was hoping for something simpler than parsing the raw email body myself (which is why I chose MailKit).  Maybe I'll see what else is out there.

Comment: Why would you need to parse the email body yourself? You aren't making any sense... MailKit already parsed it for you.

Comment: That's what I was hoping for.  I just need to know how to get at this inline image.  There is a htmlbody property, but that only contains an img tag pointing at the filename, but how do I get the actual "file".  It isn't an attachment so not in `message.Attachments`.  I would also still have to parse the img tag to find the file name, but I could live with that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would really, *really*, ***really*** recommend reading the [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#MessageBody) and/or the [README](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/README.md#getting-the-body-of-a-message) to understand how MIME is structured so that answers to questions like this become obvious, but in the meantime...

Let's start with the understanding that MIME is a tree structure, which means there's a root node (which may or may not be a leaf-node), there can be branch nodes (ex. `multipart/mixed`, `multipart/alternative`, `multipart/related`, etc.) and there are leaf-nodes (ex. `text/plain`, `text/html`, `image/jpeg`, `application/octet-stream`, etc.).

The root node of the MIME structure is the [MimeMessage.Body](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/P_MimeKit_MimeMessage_Body.htm) property.

If the message contains only a `text/plain` MIME entity, then the `MimeMessage.Body` node will *be* that `text/plain` MIME entity.

In your case, it sounds like you have at least a `text/html` entity and an `image/png` entity.

Knowing nothing else about the structure of your message, we can conclude that `MimeMessage.Body` isn't the `text/html` entity nor the `image/png` entity because you can only have 1 root node and `text/*` and `image/*` parts are leaf-node entities, not branch node entities.

That means that `MimeMessage.Body` will be a `multipart/*` which will be represented by the [Multipart](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_Multipart.htm) (or a subclass thereof).

Since it's clear that the `MimeMessage.Body` in your case is a `Multipart`, we can cast it:

```
var multipart = (Multipart) message.Body;
```

Once we have the `multipart`, we can iterate over its children:

```
foreach (var child in multipart) {
    // ...
}
```

At this point we will need to figure out if the child is another `Multipart`, a [MimePart](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MimePart.htm) (which will represent text or image data), or an embedded message (aka [MessagePart](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MessagePart.htm)).

You can use an `as` cast to quickly deduce what it is.

And then you just continue walking the tree of MIME entities until you find what you are looking for which will likely require some recursion using the above approach.

MimeKit has a few alternative ways to do this, however:

1. [MimeMessage.BodyParts](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/P_MimeKit_MimeMessage_BodyParts.htm)
2. [MimeIterator](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MimeIterator.htm)
3. and [MimeVisitor](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MimeVisitor.htm)

Here's a quick solution to your problem using the `BodyParts` property:

```
var myImage = message.BodyParts.OfType<MimePart> ().FirstOrDefault (x => x.IsMimeType ("image", "png"));
```

Comment: Yes, already read those bits.  The one bit of your answer that solved my problem was `The root node of the MIME structure is the MimeMessage.Body property.` That's the bit I needed, so thank you for that.  The fact that it is called `Body` is what threw me off.

Comment: FWIW, TextBody and HtmlBody are convenience properties that scan the tree to find the most likely text part that would represent the message body